# Is it true that $\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k = \lim_{n \to \infty}\bigcup_{k = n}^{\infty}A_k$?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

**Question:** Given a sequence of sets $\{A_k\}$, is it true that 
$$\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k = \lim_{n \to \infty}\bigcup_{k = n}^{\infty} A_k \quad ?$$

**My thoughts:** Given sets $A \subseteq B$, it's true that $A \cap B = A$. And we know for all $n \in N$ that $$\bigcup_{n+1}^{\infty}A_k \subseteq \bigcup_n^{\infty}A_k$$ so it should follow that $$\bigcup_{n+1}^{\infty}A_k \cap \bigcup_n^{\infty}A_k = \bigcup_{n+1}^{\infty}A_k.$$
Similarly, we have that 
\begin{align*}
\bigcup_{n+2}^{\infty}A_k \cap \Big( \bigcup_{n+1}^{\infty}A_k \cap \bigcup_n^{\infty}A_k \Big) = \\
 \bigcup_{n+2}^{\infty}A_k \cap\bigcup_{n+1}^{\infty}A_k = \\
\bigcup_{n+2}^{\infty}A_k
\end{align*}
and iterating like this should give the desired equality.

Is my reasoning correct? If so, why is the left-hand side of the equality usually used in the literature for probability theory instead of the right-hand side?

Comment: What does it mean for sets to have limits?

Comment: I believe the right-hand side is defined to be the left-hand side.

Comment: @angryavian: I believe the LHS is defining $\limsup$ or $\liminf$ and not $\lim$ for sets.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments everyone! So to summarize, it seems that union can be thought of as the supremum of a collection of sets (where the ordering is $\subseteq$) while intersection is the infimum.  Thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$ might be thought of as the $\limsup_{k \to \infty}A_k$. But to actually define these in terms of what we already know, we define it as stated in the problem, using the intersection of unions.